# Usefulness of explicit Isolate parameter in V8 API

Tags: v8

Some time in the past year, many functions in the V8 API were changed to have an explicit Isolate parameter.  E.g. whereas you used to write `ObjectTemplate::New()`, now you must pass in an Isolate argument: `ObjectTemplate::New(Isolate::GetCurrent())`.

Is there any reason you would ever pass an isolate other than the one returned from `GetCurrent()`?  If you were to do so, would that even work?

The reason I ask is that I'm writing bindings to use V8 for another programming language.  If the Isolate parameter is always the current isolate, I might as well omit that parameter and hardcode the call to GetCurrent in the glue layer.